# Galleria not working in IE with weird error

Tags: jquery, galleria

I have created this site and used galleria classic theme, I am so certain it was working last week!

It works well in all browsers except IE7 or IE8 it even works on iPad!. I'm getting stressed...

The Error that I'm getting is "Fatal Error: Stage Measures not found."

I have stripped the code and re-inputted and still the same error, I recently replaced the galleria code with the latest version which may be the issue but it appears in the older version, (or rather doesn't)

Here is the link
http://poppydevilleneuve.uwpistol.net/photography/the-strangers/portfolio.html

Please please this is meant to go live tomorrow. I really need help.

Comment: In the past 3 hours I have replaced the galleria code with the two previous versions.. still no joy.. It's loading the entire galleria DOM but not the images in the galleria-image div... I'm lost!

Comment: I've made a test page found here http://poppydevilleneuve.uwpistol.net/photography/the-strangers/test.html the thumbnails are displaying but not the big images..

Comment: I see, that your test gallery is working now in IE, so how did you get through with this error?

Comment: Did you solve it? I recommend using the latest version (1.2.2) the one you are using is pretty unstable in IE.

Comment: I reinstalled an older version of galleria and it seems to work fine, the measurements were being generated at run time so it was causing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the DOCTYPE problem. I had

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 //EN">
```

After the change, it works like a dream :)

Comment: I didn't realize (or rather completely forgot about) quirks mode vs. strict mode. For anyone else, this explains it pretty quick: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue, if you are using the 'classic' theme, insert a width and height for the 
.galleria-stage class in the galleria.classic.css

Answer (score 2):

If your site is built using Convio's PageBuilder CMS, this problem will appear in IE7, IE8, and IE9 (FF, Chrome, and Safari are okay). As indicated by some others, the problem is related to the Document Type Declaration. In the Convio PageBuilder CMS, this is changed under the Page Wrapper settings on the Meta Tags page - very first option. Change from HTML 4.0 Transitional (quirks mode) to XHTML 1.0 Transitional (standards-compliance mode).